# How to use hex colour for SolidColorBrush with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, textblock, solidcolorbrush

I'm trying to use a hex colour (`#E32017`) programmatically for text within a textblock but it's not working. Does anyone know how a hex colour can used instead of `Colors.Red` when it comes to textblocks for Windows Phone?

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "H", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
```

Comment: What colour do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use `#E32017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [Color.FromArgb method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify the individual red, green, and blue components of your color:

```
Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xE3, 0x20, 0x17))
```

Comment: Doesn't work as I get this error: `'System.Windows.Media.Color' does not contain a definition for 'FromRgb'`.

Comment: Sorry, looks like FromRgb isn't available on Windows Phone. Try using FromArgb instead.